# Android User Interface Design

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

Why LinearLayout doesn't re-sizes on different screens?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are using it!

If you want your layout to be resized automatically you can specify a [weight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_weight) parameter to the views composing your `LinearLayout`.

For example:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:weightSum="1"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
>
   <SomeView
      android:layout_width="0dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="0.5"
    />

   <SomeView
      android:layout_width="0dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="0.5"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

In this case your two subviews will share the whole horizontal space and each one of them will take 50% of the space.